# How to merge exisiting python modules with conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed Python 3.10 and then install Anaconda separately, so now everytime I use pip, the new packages is not usable in Jupyter kernel, and I have to reinstall it inside that kernel again.

Is there a way to merge these two environments or paths ( closest term I can think of to call this, sorry) together so when I install a new module and/or package on one, it can be used in another?

Example install tabulate using pip from cmd, then open Jupyter Notebook it can use table from tabulate.

I tried googled and searching on here but all returned was using conda -merge or changing paths or related, which is not what I want to do.